# hostapd doesent work anymore

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-3b+, access-point, hostapd

I was running hostapd and it worked fine but i had to reinstall the os and copied the config but now it gives me some problems.
First of all hostapd was masked, then i unmasked it and tried to start it but it doesent work.

service hostapd status

```
un/hostapd.pid -B /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

: Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
: wlan0: Could not connect to kernel driver
: Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr b8:27:eb:93:08:7c and ssid "Wifi"
: random: Cannot read from /dev/random: Resource temporarily unavailable
: random: Only 0/20 bytes of strong random data available from /dev/random
: random: Not enough entropy pool available for secure operations
: WPA: Not enough entropy in random pool for secure operations - update keys lat
: wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED
: wlan0: AP-ENABLED
Started Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator.
```

hostapd.conf

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=Wifi
hw_mode=g
# country_code=US
channel=9
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=password
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
# ieee80211n=1
# ieee80211d=1
```

Comment: I always thought a "country code" has to be specified for wifi to work at all on a pi3+

Answer (score 1):

Did you update your Pi?
If not run sudo apt-get update && upgrade, you Pi needs to update once in a while, it happends to me if I do not update it, and if that does not fix it run, sudo apt-get update --fix-missing

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled everything from scratch, now it seems to work... I noticed that the openvpn client does some interference during startup..